# Unhandled Rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to handle **(node:29804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: test1 first throw**
, does any one have an idea of how i can cleanly handle it ?
I am not interested in using await in this situation.

```
const test0 = async () => {
  try {
    throw('test0 first throw');
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('test0 last catch');
    throw('test0 last throw');
  }
}

const test1 = async () => {
  try {
    test0()
    .catch(e => {
     console.log('test1 first catch');
     throw('test1 first throw'); // This throws unhandled exception
    })
//    return(0);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('test1 last catch');
    throw('test1 last throw');
  }
}

const caller = async () => {
  try {
    let res = test1().
      catch(e => {
        console.log('PRE FINAL CATCH');
      })
    console.log(res);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('FINAL CATCH');
//    console.log(e);
  }
}

caller();
```

Comment: The clean way to do it would be to just not throw at all at that point, since there aren't any other handlers to deal with the thrown error

Comment: Im basically trying to pass the rejection to the the caller function, should those try catch and just .catch be able to handle it ?

Comment: No, because `test0` is asynchronous, but you said you didn't want to use `await`, so there's no way to chain the `test0` and its `catch` with the `try/catch` in `test1`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little uncommon to see a mix of `try/catch` and `then()/catch()` styles of handling promises.

You could remove the all the uneccessary try/catches and `return` where needed. No `await` involved. If an error happens somewhere in the other functions, it'll be logged and thrown back up to `caller`:

```js
const test0 = async () => {
  try {
    throw('test0 first throw');
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('test0 last catch');
    throw('test0 last throw');
  }
}

const test1 = async () => {
  return test0()
    .catch(e => {
     console.log('test1 first catch');
     throw('test1 first throw'); // This throws unhandled exception
    });
}

const caller = async () => {
  return test1().catch((e) => {
     console.log('PRE FINAL CATCH');
  });
}

caller();
```

If there are other requirements, I'm happy to amend this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, i ended up doing some more reading on how async error handling works here: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-async-function-error-handling-is-not-what-you-think-dac10a98edb2

And ended up going with this code structure.
The idea was so have a similar function structure and error handling for async and awaited functions.
The reason i prefer to the try/catch block in this example is because it will catch all the other errors which may be within that function

// If you can NOT use await in the caller function then follow structure A

/************* BEGIN STRUCTURE A *************/

```
const handlerFnA = async(fnParam) => { await fnParam(); }

const fnDispatcherA = async () => {
  try{
    await handlerFnA(innerAsyncFnA);
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log('error caught in fnDispatcher: ', e);
  }
}

const innerAsyncFnA = async () => {
  try {
    throw('I am an error from innerAsyncFn');
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('innerAsyncFn catch');
    throw(e);
  }
}

const callerA = async () => {
  try {
    fnDispatcherA();
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('caller catch');
  }
}
```

/*********** END STRUCTURE A ************/

// If you can use await in the caller function then follow structure B

/************* BEGIN STRUCTURE B *************/

```
const handlerFnB = async(fnParam) => { await fnParam(); }

const innerAsyncFnB = async () => {
  try {
    throw('I am an error from innerAsyncFn');
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('innerAsyncFn catch');
    throw(e);
  }
}

const callerB = async () => {
  try {
    await handlerFnB(innerAsyncFnB);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('caller catch');
  }
}
```

/*********** END STRUCTURE B ************/

```
callerB();
```